# Journey Builder Reporting by Domain

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, journeybuilder

When I'm in the analytics builder - reports, I want to pull a report of a Journey send.  Is that possible?  When I select that report from the reports catalog, it doesn't show the `Journey Builder` folder where I can select those sends.

All in all, I'm having some trouble with GMAIL classifying us as SPAM.
I also have ReturnPath set up within our SFMC account, but again, I'm not able to follow a Journey Builder campaign because they are treated as triggered sends and are outside out seeded lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not available out of the box. I have seen instances where enterprise level client request that this be added to their accounts at a cost.

Your other option is to use queries to generate these report in. This will be a query on the `_Sent` table `WHERE EmailAddress LIKE '%@gmail.%'`

Answer (score 1):

With the addition of Datorama Reports, you can now build a Pivot Table to replicate this report 1:1 with the data formerly provided in the Email Performance for All Domains.

To re-create this report:

1. Navigate to Datorama Reports > Pivot Tables > Create Pivot Table
2. Provide a PivotTable Name and the date range you need.
3. Update Settings: Add Filter on Journey Name (alternatively Journey ID). Rows - Email Domain. Values - Email Sends, Email Deliveries, Email Delivery Rate, Email Bounces, Email Bounce Rate, Email Unique Opens, Email Open Rate, Email Unique Clicks, Email Click Rate, Email Unique Unsubscribes, Email Unsubscribe Rate

[image: Edit Pivot Table Settings]

4. Hit Apply
5. You may receive a Row Limit Exceeded warning. Click OK

[image: Row Limit Exceeded Warning]

6. Save your work (bottom right)
7. Click Save & Download on the Row Limit screen or Export (top nav) with your desired output options.

Visit the Trailhead module for more information on [Datorama Reports for Marketing Cloud](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/datorama-reports-for-marketing-cloud).